# .NET Core console application with EF Core is not working when run from using dotnet run command, throwing authentication failed exception

Tags: c#, .net-core, console, ef-core-3.0, dotnet-cli

I wrote a simple .NET Core console application to explore EF Core using the code first approach and I followed the below steps (windows machine).

1. Create a new .NET Core console application

```
dotnet new console -o CodeFirstDemo
```

2. cd into the `CodeFirstDemo` directory

```
cd CodeFirstDemo
```

3. run the application, which compile and produce the output

```
dotnet run
```

4. Now to start Entity Framework Core, add the EF Core package for SQL Server

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

5. Open the `CodeFirstDemo` directory in VS code

```
code .
```

6. Add a new file called `Posts.cs` to the project via VS code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace CodeFirstDemo 
{
    public class Post 
    {
        public int PostId {get; set;}
        public DateTime DatePublished {get; set;}
        public string Description {get; set;}
        public string Body {get; set;}
    }
}
```

7. Add another file called `BlogDBContext.cs` via VS code

```
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Configuration;

namespace CodeFirstDemo 
{
    public class BlogDBContext : DbContext 
    {
        public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
            => options.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=CodeFirstDemo;Trusted_Connection=True;");
    }
}
```

8. Update the `Program.cs` file as shown below

```
using System;

namespace CodeFirstDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Creating dbcontext...");
            BlogDBContext dbContext = new BlogDBContext();

            Console.WriteLine("Creating post entry...");

            Post post = new Post()
            {
                // do not insert PostId because it is marked as Identity column
                DatePublished = DateTime.Now,
                Description = "Description.",
                Body = "Body."
            };

            Console.WriteLine("Adding post to posts dbset...");
            dbContext.Posts.Add(post);

            Console.WriteLine("Saving to database!");
            dbContext.SaveChanges();

            // wait for input to keep the console open
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

9. Now run the program

```
dotnet run
```

10. The program fails with this `SqlException` (0x80131904):

```
Creating dbcontext...
Creating post entry...
Adding post to posts dbset...
Saving to database!
```

> Unhandled exception. Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "CodeFirstDemo" requested by the login. The login failed.

How to fix this error?

Comment: Note: If you did not override `OnConfiguring()` but you used an external source to specify the connection string (for example via `appsettings.json` or `secret.json`) then you would need to implement `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory`.

Answer (score 4):

After jumping between different answers, I ended up at the below article, which helped me solve the SqlException (0x80131904).

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/?tabs=netcore-cli#create-the-database
```

Run the below commands to fixed the issue.

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
dotnet ef database update
```

Output for migrations command:

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Done. To undo this action, use 'ef migrations remove'
```

Output for update command:

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Applying migration '20200704134852_InitialCreate'.
Done.
```

Check the Sql server for the creation of CodeFirstDemo database and run the application.

```
dotnet run
```

Output:

```
Creating dbcontext...
Creating post entry...
Adding post to posts dbset...
Saving to database!
```

Goto the SQL Server and check the record successfully added to the `CodeFirstDemo` database.

Note: I used SQL Server Object Explorer in Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 to access SQL Server.